Go templates how access to global scope data?
Let's assume that I pass two types of data to the template (its only simple EXAMPLE):
type User struct {
   UserId string
   Username string
}

type Group struct {
  GroupName string
  GroupMembers []Users
}

func GroupDetails(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  data := map[string]any{}
  var tGroups []Group
  var tUsers []User 
  
  tGroups := LoadGroupsFromDatabase()
  tUsers = LoadUsersFromDatabase()

  data['groups'] = tGroup
  data['allUsers'] = tUsers

  myTemplate := template.ParseFiles("templates/groups.tmpl")
  err := myTemplate.ExecuteTemplate(w, "groups", data)
}

and template:
{{ block "groups" . }}
{{ template "AllUsers" .allUsers }} <!- this works fine -->
{{ range .groups }}
  {{ template "GroupDetails" . }} 
{{ end }} <!- end groups range ->
{{ end }} <!- end block --> 

{{ block "GroupDetails" . }}
Group name : {{ .GroupName }}
  Group members :
  {{ range .GroupMembers }}
     {{ UserName }}
  {{ end }} <!- end range grup members ->  
  Add users:
  {{ template AllUsers $.allUsers }} <<-- How call "global" variable here ???
{{ end }}

{{ block "AllUsers" . }}
  {{ range . }}
    {{ UserName }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }} 

When i try access from groups range scope to "global" allUsers variable got error:
executing "groups" at <$.allUsers>: can't evaluate field allUsers in type *Group

Which is understandable, the dot there is context-aware, but how to get to the global variable? $.AllUsers works only in "global" block but in sub-block/range it doesn't work anymore.
As a workaround in some cases, I came up with passing . instead of .group to the sub-block, but accessing the global variable would be much more convenient (and work in ranges context).

Variables defined in an outer scope are not global. A block only knows about its conrext
